# Updating Label with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm making a currency converter in Python 3.7 and I'm using tkinter for the interface. I need help with making the label update when a button is pressed, because currently the label simply stacks beneath the current label.

I looked at some solutions but none work for my current code.

JUST TO CLARIFY: the code below is copy-pasted 10 times for 10 different currencies and each has a bound button, I need the label to update regardless of which one of the 10 I press.

Thanks in advance!

````
def convert1():                                                              
    global kol                                                                                                                                     
    x = kol.get()                                                                                                                                  
    global euro                                                                                                                                    
    finalno = x * euro                                                                                                                             
    fnl = Label(root, text = "HRK:" + str(finalno)).pack()                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ```
````

Comment: Why are you making a new label each time? Try using only one label, and `label.config(text="...")` for each procedure.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I could put everything into one label?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a new label for each output, just make one label, and change its contents using `label.config(text=...)`. Here's an example of how that could be done:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

O = Label(root, text="") #  defining the *one* label we will use
O.pack()

E = Entry(root)
E.pack()

def convert():
    result = float(E.get()) / 2
    O.config(text=str(result))

B = Button(root, text="convert", command=convert)
B.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

For your program, you want to create several buttons, linking to different functions for different conversions, or you should be able to use `lambda` functions and keep each conversion to just the one line.